# Tools to see which contract addresses have approval to spend your tokens and revoke access to them in bulk?

Tags: contract-development, security, permissions

Is there a tool to see which contract addresses have spend permissions for my tokens? And potentially revoke them if needed in bulk.

Comment: Never see this, but it is a good idea for implementation =)

Comment: good list here: https://twitter.com/Darrenlautf/status/1495212769750429699

Answer (score 5):

Sites like [revoke.cash](https://revoke.cash/) and [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tokenapprovalchecker) can help you with this. Neither allow you to revoke in bulk though.

Answer (score 1):

As the creator of [Revoke.cash](https://revoke.cash) I can go into a bit more detail as to *why* neither Revoke.cash nor Etherscan or other tools support bulk revoking, as **ruvaag** mentioned in their answer.

Approving an allowance is done using the `approve()` function of an ERC20 token or the `setApprovalForAll()` function of an ERC721 token. When calling these functions, an approval is set for the address that called this function (`msg.sender`), which may be an EOA or a smart contract address. Using `msg.sender` is an important security feature, because then you know for sure that no smart contract can set allowances on behalf of someone else.

The way *bulk actions* are usually done on Ethereum is by having a smart contract that bundles different actions together, such as bulk transferring NFTs through [0xmons' multisender](https://0xmons.xyz/#/multisender). But because allowances are always set for the address that calls the `approve()` function, this would mean that this "bulk contract" would be the one setting allowances for itself, rather than the user initiating the transaction.

This is why every allowance needs to be approved or revoked directly from the address that it applies to. And because there is no *native* bulk functionality in Ethereum, this means you have to send a single transaction per allowance you want to revoke.

Answer (score 0):

There is this project on GitHub: https://github.com/James-Sangalli/eth-allowance.
It allows you to see all the addresses that have permission to spend your tokens on your behalf, and more. You can delete all of them in bulk or select one by one.

**UPDATE:**
This is the site where the project has been deployed: https://ethallowance.com/

*Note:* In the last month, they have implemented the support for BSC mainnet.